# Isotope remove single item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I've used Isotope on one of my project and ran into a problem. I want to remove items by clicking the button in the element and after removing the item, I want the layout to reload. This is working for only the first item on small screens, but not for the other two on large screens. The item is removed, but the transition and layout are not updating/working. Can someone help me? Here is my Fiddle (which is working because it's a small screen, enlarge to see the problem):

```
 var $grid = $('.js-grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.js-grid-item'
});

$grid.on('click', '.js-grid-item .js-delete', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    $grid.isotope();
    $grid.isotope('reloadItems')
    $grid.isotope('layout');
    return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3982db13/

Comment: have you checked the docs?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to happen, but here are two different ways that I changed your code using the isotope docs: https://jsfiddle.net/3982db13/3/show/ and https://jsfiddle.net/3982db13/4/show/

Comment: Are you sure that `$(this).parent().parent()` goes high enough? You might try `$(this).closest(".js-grid-item").remove()`.

Comment: That works, thanks so much!